# PHP including files inside classes

Tags: php

Just a quick question, but I've been working on a small MVC framework and noticed something.

For example:

--PHP file--

```
class loadFiles{
        function __construct($file = NULL){
        include $file . '.php';
        }
}
$loadfiles = new $loadFiles('crucialsettings');
echo $randomstring; //Throws an error
```

--crucialsettings.php--

```
<?php
    $randomstring = 'hello';
?>
```

I only just realised that files included inside an objects scope are inaccessable from the global scope. What is the best way to include a file inside an object so it can be accessed globally?

I would like to be able to:

```
$loadfiles->settings();
$loadfiles->classes();
$loadfiles->passwords();
```

I want to build a class that handles global file includes.

Comment: include is the same as cut and pasting the code from the file in a text editor. So what ever is inserted that is what will be executed as PHP source code.

Comment: You can use `$GLOBALS['randomstring'] = 'hello';` if you want to set it in the global scope.

Comment: Is this actual working code? If so, then you need to read up on how to instantiate objects. See the [`new`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) keyword.

Comment: Sorry, no this is untested code I just made up with my answer. Oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you include or require code from in PHP.  The interpreter is pretty linear in it's first definition pass, that is to say that it will basically compress all of the included / required files into one large file in the exact order in how it was read.

One thing to note about this is that scope does change. but everything is applied to the "global" scope.  You can always import something from the global scope into your current scope using the "global" keyword to declare a variable prior to using it.  So when you want to use a "global" variable from another script just ask for it.

A little example...

**a.php**

```
include('b.php');
global $myVar;
echo $myVar;
```

**b.php**

```
include('c.php');
```

**c.php**

```
$myVar = 'Hello World';
```

**What the interpreter see's this code as after it's first pass**

```
// In global scope
$myVar = 'Hello World'

// In a.php scope
global $myVar;
echo $myVar;
```

In short from your php file simply add the line

```
global $randomstring;
```

After you include the crucialsettings.php file and your echo will work.

Comment: Is it not bad to use globals in this way? I've been told "don't use globals unless absolutely necessary" from various sources

Comment: Everything in PHP is global, execution just slips into private scopes during the execution of files.  That is to say that the act of using the "global" keyword to import something is just declaring access to a variable that's already there.  Good OOP practice is that you would put all of your variables into a class to avoid scoping issues.  Using the keyword is not bad, designing your code so you have to use the global keyword may be looked down on by other coders.  In the end performance wise there's no difference so whatever works for you is best.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll do a little more research and see if anyone else has an alternative solution.

Comment: Also, what I was worried about was having function and class definitions inside an object if included. It sounds untidy.

Comment: That's a totally different concept, but to put it simply in PHP you either define a function as procedural (not in a class or object) or as an object method (inside a class or object).   Writing a procedural function that takes a class as an argument is virtual blaspheme of both programming styles in my opinion.  If you need a function to do something to a class write it as a class member.  If you need to pass an entire object to a function to make it work go back to the drawing board and figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: What I was meaning is that if you use include inside an object method you will be effectively defining the included functions inside the object. Will it still not matter?

Comment: no the code does not execute in the same scope as the parent file.  Functions from the included file are defined the same no matter where you include it from.

Answer (score 1):

Appears that your framework here is too reliant on non-OOP for its innards.  Not a preferable way to build up, but you **can** do what you want by cycling through list of variables and making them part of your class/instance scope.  A rather helpful function here is [get_defined_vars();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

Lets say you have files a.php, b.php and c.php.  Each looks like this:

**a.php**: `<?php $a = "AAAAAA";`

**b.php**: `<?php $b = "BBBBBBBBBB";`

**c.php**: `<?php $c = "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC";`

```
class mystuff {
    function include_with_vars( $____file ) {

        // grab snapshot of variables, exclude knowns
        $____before = get_defined_vars();
        unset( $____before['____file'] );

        // include file which presumably will add vars
        include( $____file );

        // grab snapshot of variables, exclude knowns again
        $____after = get_defined_vars();
        unset( $____after['____file'] );
        unset( $____after['____before'] );

        // generate a list of variables that appear to be new
        $____diff = array_diff( $____after, $____before );

        // put all local vars in instance scope
        foreach( $____diff as $variable_name => $variable_value ) {
            $this->$variable_name = $variable_value;
        }
    }

    function __construct($file = NULL){
        $this->include_with_vars( "a.php" );
        $this->include_with_vars( "b.php" );
        $this->include_with_vars( "c.php" );
    }
}

$t = new mystuff();
echo "<PRE>"; 
print_r( $t );
```

This program will now take local variables from your include() directives and put them in the class scope:

```
mystuff Object
(
    [a] => AAAAAA
    [b] => BBBBBBBBBB
    [c] => CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
)
```

In other words, your local variables from file a.php (`$a`) are now `$t->a`.